# Create click-through overlay instruction view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview

A really simple question here.
How do you create a view like this? 
[image]

It has to overlay the first time user runs this part of the app and be removed forever once the user taps on it. I understand it should be a UIImageView, but how do you make it active and then remove it from the view forever?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add your subview just after your app launch in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of your app delegate by using the `addSubView` method of the `UIView` class. Here are some code snippets of how you could proceed:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] 
    initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
    [self.window addSubview:imageView];

     UITapGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
     recognizer.delegate = self;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled =  YES;
    self.imageView = imageView;
}

- (void) handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognize
{
     [self.imageView removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Note that you will need a property to reference your imageView in the `handleTap` method.

Comment: I got "Assigning to 'id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'AppDelegate *'" - any advise? Thanks!

Comment: you need to make your AppDelegate comply to the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate by declaring something like this: yourAppDelegate()<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

Answer (score 4):

[`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) has all the methods you need, e.g.

- Call `[myView addSubview:imgView]` to add the image view to the current view (`myView`)
- Call `[imgView removeFromSuperview]` when finish (i.e. in respond to tap or after a timer)

Make sure `userInteractionEnabled` property of `imgView` to `NO` so that touches are passed to `myView`.

Comment: why not having the subView handling the tap?

Comment: You can, but the question asks for "click-through" behavior, so I suppose the poster'd prefer to have the background view to handle touches.

Comment: ok his title is missleading. He mentioned though: "It has to overlay the first time user runs this part of the app and be removed forever once the user taps on it" so he obviously want the tap to occur on the overlay view

Comment: From the user's perspective, the tap will occur on the overlay (because, well, it's overlaying); the code handling the tap could sit in either view.

Comment: Just note that userInteractionEnabled property is set to NO as default for UIImageView

Comment: @tiguero: you're right about the property; I just mentioned because it's a crucial fact for the click-through behavior

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts would be set an NSUserDefault variable and check it on applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions or somewhere else in your app that makes sense. You could just push a separate view when your variable is true vs. false.