# Click-through overlay code in AppDelegate does not work. How to fix these errors?

Tags: ios, uiview, appdelegate

Sorry about the vague question but I don't know how to make it more specific because I don't know what is wrong with the code. You guys probably can tell right away what those errors mean.

I'm trying to get overlay image to show up when the app is started and then to make the overlay go away with a tap gesture. I just can't get this to work. I got the code from a different SO question (link: [Create click-through overlay instruction view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289756/create-click-through-overlay-instruction-view?answertab=active#tab-top)). **Any ideas what I'm missing here?** My code shows the error messages that I receive (2 errors, 1 warning).

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIImageView *overlay = [[UIImageView alloc]
                            initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"overlayImg.png"]];
    [self.window addSubview:overlay];

    UITapGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    recognizer.delegate = self; //WARNING: Assigning to 'id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>'from incompatible type 'AppDelegate *const__strong'
    [overlay addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    overlay.userInteractionEnabled =  YES;
    self.overlay = overlay; //ERROR: Property 'overlay' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void) handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    [self.overlay removeFromSuperView]; //ERROR: Property 'overlay' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'
}
```

Comment: code above has a typo. "removeFromSuperView" should say "removeFromSuperview". Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ether remove the line

```
recognizer.delegate = self;
```

or implement the delegate. Add this at the top of AppDelegate.m to get rid of the warning.

```
@interface AppDelegate () <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@end
```

And it looks like, that you are missing the `UIImageView` property.
Go and add the property to the interface extension above. This should look like so:

```
@interface AppDelegate () <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *overlay;
@end
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I'm close... I can feel it. These got rid off errors and warning but now the last error message changed. This line: [self.overlay removeFromSuperView]; gives now this error message: No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'removeFromSuperView'. But if I comment this line out, the app does not load the overlay image, am I missing something else?

Comment: Alright. Got rid of the last error message (see my previous comment above). Reason for that was my typo, it's "removeFromSuperview" not "removeFromSuperView". Now the app runs without errors or warning but no overlay image?

Comment: Move the code to your ViewController or to the AppDelegates applicationDidBecomeActive: method. The Image is displayed behind the ViewController's view. And add the gesture recognizer to self.window instead the overlay. I highly recommend to move the code to your ViewController.

Comment: I took your advise and moved the code to ViewController and did the needed changes. Voila, it works! Thank you so much for your patience!