# Do you use UIActivityIndicator for the gray translucent instructions?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to iOS, clearly. I'm looking for either a tutorial or something of the like, that shows me how to create a gray overlay that tells the user how to use the application. It's largely driven by touch, so I'd like to tell the user where to touch the first time they use the application to do specific things. Thanks for the help!

Also, for general questions like this, am I posting in the correct section of stackoverflow?

Comment: UIActivityIndicator is the spinning wheel that tells the user that something is happening. To create what you are looking for you need to create a custom view and do most of it yourslef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the same question of mine - [Create click-through overlay instruction view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289756/create-click-through-overlay-instruction-view)

Your question has nothing to do with `UIActivityIndicator`, though.

In your `AppDelegate` you can declare wether it should be shown only at the first time the user opened the app. It can be anything you like. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Just create an `UIView` with the size of the window and `alpha` value < 1 (with interface builder)

Then add `UILabels` or any other component with the help info as subviews of the overlay help.

when you want to show it, just change it's `hidden` property to `NO`, and when you want to hide it change the `hidden` to `YES`